# Python: Sum List of Dictionary Values

Tags: python, list

I have the following structure:

```
"Labour": [{
    "load": 5.00
}, {
    "edge": 0.00
}, {
    "unload": 5.00
}, {
    "load": 5.00
}, {
    "edge": 0.00
}, {
    "unload": 5.00
}, {
    "load": 5.00
}, {
    "edge": 0.00
}, {
    "unload": 5.00
}, {
    "load": 0.00
}, {
    "edge": 0.00
}, {
    "unload": 0.00
}, {
    "load": 0.00
}, {
    "edge": 0.00
}, {
    "unload": 0.00
}],
```

How do I add the values so that, all the load, edge, unload etc are sum together. Also, the dictionary has more keys, I also need to search and add them by keys. I'm using Python 2.7.

Comment: You need to write a program that reads this file (looks like incomplete JSON) and does the summation.

Comment: What kind of a result do you want to have? a dict? or just maybe just a sum? Give examples please

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a `Counter` to accumulate all the values from all the keys in each dictionary:

```
from collections import Counter

lst = [{
    "load": 5.00
},
...,
{
    "edge": 0.00
}]

dct = Counter()

for d in lst:
   for k, v in d.items():
      dct[k] += v 

print(dct)
# Counter({'load': 15.0, 'unload': 15.0, 'edge': 0.0})
print(sum(dct.values()))
# 30
```

This works fine if you don't need to manage negative counts, otherwise, you'll need to use say `collections.defaultdict`, setting the default factory as `float`.

Comment: Beautiful! Worked like a charm. Thanks Moses.

Comment: @MuhitAnik You may consider accepting one of the answers if you think they helped.

Answer (score 1):

```
sum([i.values()[0] for i in list_of_dicts])
```

If you need to select only values corresponding to set of specific keys, you could do something like this:

```
keys=['load', 'edge' ] 
sum([i[k] for k in keys for i in list_of_dicts if k in i])
```

Comment: It did not work. I got key error.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
total = 0
for item in dic['Labour']:
    for val in item.values():
        total += val
```

Edit:

If you only want the same type summed together you could do this instead:

```
total = {}

for item in dic['Labour']:
    for key,val in item.items():
        if key in total:
            total[key] +=val
        else:
            total[key] = val
```

Comment: @AGNGazer I guess that would work as well, but if any of the internal dicts has more than 1 values that would not work.

Comment: Thank You so much.

Comment: @MuhitAnik No worries! Hope the answer helped!

Answer (score 0):

simple straightforward:

if your dictionary is ( i added two new values ):

```
d = {"Labour": [{"load": 5.00}, 
           {"edge": 0.00}, 
           {"unload": 5.00}, 
           {"load": 5.00}, 
           {"edge": 0.00}, 
           {"unload": 5.00}, 
           {"load": 5.00}, 
           {"edge": 0.00}, 
           {"unload": 5.00}, 
           {"load": 0.00}, 
           {"edge": 0.00}, 
           {"unload": 0.00}, 
           {"load": 0.00}, 
           {"edge": 0.00}, 
           {"unload": 0.00}, 
           {"new_val": 5.00}, 
           {"new_val_2": 5.00}],}
```

then you can define this small function:

```
def sum_dicts_by_key(k, biglist):
    sum = 0
    for sdict in biglist['Labour']:
        sum += sdict.get(k,0)
    return sum
```

and then use it like :

```
sum_by_key = dict()
for small_dict in d['Labour']:
    k = small_dict.keys()[0]
    sum_by_key[k] = sum_dicts_by_key(k, d)

print('key list %s' % sum_by_key.keys())
print('Sum by key %s' % sum_by_key)
print('Total sum %s' % sum(sum_by_key.values()))
```

and the result is :

```
key list ['load', 'new_val', 'edge', 'new_val_2', 'unload']
Sum by key {'load': 15.0, 'new_val': 5.0, 'edge': 0.0, 'new_val_2': 
            5.0, 'unload': 15.0}
Total sum 40.0
```

Comment: Thanks for the wonderful solution.